# Nonlinear relation between two variables as affected by two interacting treatments

Tags: anova, lme4-nlme, biostatistics, ancova

I experimentally tested the relation between dependent variable y (continuous) and independent variable x (continuous) for 6 replicates x 2 genotypes (categorical) x 3 species (categorical) each (= treatment A) that were grown in 3 differently pre-treated soils (categorical, = treatment B), resulting in 108 plants. The experiment was conducted in different greenhouses (GH) at the same time whereby the genotype-soil combinations were distributed randomly. I primarily want to know if the relation between y and x differs between soils (a). I also want to know if the relation between y and x differs between the two plant varieties per species when they were grown in the same soil (b). I want to account for the greenhouse as potential random effect.

[image]

I can fit `y ~ x`  like:

(a)

```r
 model_list <- list()
unique_soils <- unique(d_sub$Soil)
for (soil in unique_soils) {
  sub_data <- d_sub[d_sub$Soil == soil, ]
  fit <- nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, asymp, infl, slope1), data = sub_data)
  model_list[[paste("fit_", soil, sep = "")]] <- fit
}
```

(b)

```r
model_list <- list()
unique_soils <- unique(d_sub$Soil)
unique_Genotypes <- unique(d_sub$Genotype)
for (soil in unique_soils) {
  sub<- d_sub[d_sub$Soil == soil, ] 
  for (Genotype in unique_Genotypes) {
  sub_data <- sub[sub$Genotype == Genotype, ]
  fit <- nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, asymp, infl, slope1), data = sub_data)
  model_list[[paste("fit_", Genotype,'_',soil, sep = "")]] <- fit
  }
}
```

My table looks like this (example):

```r
> head(d_sub)
        ID           Genotype  Soil GH         y        x  Species
1   311019 SpeciesB_GenotypeA SoilA  1 0.1542170 1.482907 SpeciesB
2   311019 SpeciesB_GenotypeA SoilA  1 0.2033631 1.715033 SpeciesB
3   311019 SpeciesB_GenotypeA SoilA  1 0.2762349 2.365915 SpeciesB
```

What is the best way of testing if the **relation between y and x** statistically differs between soils and genotypes of the same species grown in the same soil?
I was thinking of:

1. Using ANOVA to compare if the resulting models differ significantly from each other. I am not sure if that is valid because my models are non-linear.
2. Create an nlme with soil and genotype as interaction factors (I did not find out how to code that in R).
3. Extracting the fitted parameters *asymp, infl, slope1* and use statistical tests to compare them amongst each other between the treatments. I do not know how to account for the standard error/ confidence intervals of the fitted parameters.