# Statistical significance between sigmoidal regression curves

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures, nls

I have a data-set of weight ~ temperature that was measured in 3 species (A-B-C), each consisting of 2 genotypes (a-b) that were grown in 3 soils (1-2-3) each. Weight ~ temperature for each Soil x Genotype x Species combination (18 possible combinations in total) can be fitted as:

```r
m = nls(weight ~ Asym/(1 + exp((xmid-temperature)/scal)), data=sub, 
        start=list(Asym=0.5212, xmid=2.8174, scal=1.5915))
```

How can I determine if the resulting curves are significantly different from each other? I should mention that temperature is a continous variable that increases over time, meaning that it is kind of a repeated measurements-problem.

Comment: You would first have to say what, precisely, you mean by "different".

Comment: I guess in order to know if the curves differ, I want to know if the obtained regression parameters Asym, xmid and scal differ significantly between Soils, Species and Genotypes per Species.

Comment: The simple approach would be to fit each curve and treat each fit of parameters as a new observed variable.

Comment: Where is the time variable in this equation, or is temperature equivalent to time? It would be nice when you explain the experiment more in detail.

Comment: If all measurements would be independent and error distribution heteroskedastic, then you could use a chi-squared statistic or anova. But likely you have correlated measurement, and homoskedastic error distribution.

Comment: How many repetitions do you have for the 18 combinations?

Comment: @ Sextus Empiricus, that is what I did but it got critizised as I cannot take the confidence intervals of the fitted parameters into account like this. 

Temperature was increased with time and weight was measured for each new temperature level once temperature has stabilized, meaning per measured sample, I have weights for 6 consecutive temperature-levels. For each Soils x Species x Genotypes per Species - combination, I have 6 replicates.

Comment: It basically looks like this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/639337/nonlinear-relation-between-two-variables-as-affected-by-two-interacting-treatmen

Comment: Those data look in certain aspects clearly different, like the different soil types have a clear influence. But the differences in species is not so clear and the effects of genotype and interactions between species and genotype are neither clear. In addition, the applicability of the logistic models is not so clear and interpretations of the models parameters might be tricky (the curves are mostly nearly linear with only slight curves/difference at the edges). For exploratory analysis, I would prefer plots of the average values, rather than the fitted curves.